# ToyVpnService throws PortUnreachableException and times out after initial connection

Tags: networking, network-interface, vpn, android

I built the ToyVPNClient for Android from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn and am also running the server code on my Linux machine. I used the following commands to create the tun0 tunneling interface:

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo ip tuntap add dev tun0 mod tun
sudo ifconfig tun0 10.0.0.1 dstaddr 10.0.0.2 up
./ToyVpnServer tun0 8000 test -m 1400 -a 10.0.0.2 32 -d 8.8.8.8 -r 0.0.0.0
```

After these steps, I can see the tun0 interface on doing ifconfig.

I provide my Linux machine's address to the VPN Client app and the port 8000 and the shared secret and initially the handshake occurs successfully and the client receives the parameters of the tunneling interface from the server. But after a short time, the client starts throwing errors like:

```
E/ToyVpnService: Got java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timed out
E/ToyVpnService: Got java.net.PortUnreachableException:
```

This is followed by another successful connect and handshake and this keeps repeating. After the initial connection and transfer of parameters, I only occasionally see a packet being received by the tunnel. Could anyone who has experience with the ToyVpn tell me what this is happening. I have also disabled the ufw firewall but that does not seem to help.